# Fence post on concrete slab

Tags: fence, backyard

I'm looking to build a fence around my backyard, which already has a concrete slab laid where I want to place the fence.

Would anchoring a fence post there be structurally safe? I think the slab is about 2 inches thick.

[image]

Comment: is it wood or metal fence post.

Comment: I'm open to either wood or metal. Haven't picked out my materials yet. What should I do? Take it out and pour a footing?

Comment: FYI- Attempting to anchor a metal post base to the concrete then putting a wooden post in that will leave you with a _very_ wobbly post. I attempted that for a stair railing and it was _very_ unsatisfying. I ended up pulling the base and attaching the posts with a different method.

Answer (score 3):

Rent a fence post driller and drill at least 2 feet deep) in the ground next to the concrete walk way. You can also manually dig.

First make sure there are no water or electricity lines there.

Your concrete is not thick (strong enough) to hold fence posts.
If you put fence pots on the edge of the concrete that will not work, and you walk way will become narrow.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @ruskes that the slab is not thick enough.  Rent a hole auger and a concrete saw (might be able to get through it with a 4.5" angle grinder too).  Dig down a couple of feet and fill with concrete.

On my last fence project, I used these [cast-in-place post bases](https://www.strongtie.com/standoffpostbases_castinplacepostbases/pbs_base/p/pbs).  They are not listed for fence posts and Simpson says they don't provide rotational support, which is true, but mine feel very very solid and have stood up to a couple of strong wind events already.  I expect them to last 10-20 years, maybe longer because the lumber is an inch above the concrete.